# Post 'multipart/form-data' out of Salesforce.com APEX

Tags: http, salesforce, apex-code

I have an APEX Method that attempts to *Post* a form to a remote endpoint out of SFDC's APEX Code.

Everything seems to encode correctly, and the server sends back a 200 response, but the attachment isn't arriving with the request... is SFDC removing the content of my post body before it's sent?

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Authorization','Basic '+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf('removed:removed')));
req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------------153501500631101');
req.setHeader('X-Atlassian-Token','nocheck');
req.setMethod('POST');  
req.setEndpoint(endPoint+'issue/'+c.Internal_Bug_Number__c+'/attachments');

String body = '-----------------------------153501500631101\r\n';
body = body + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filedata"; filename="'+attachments[0].Name+'"\r\n';
body = body + 'Content-Type: '+attachments[0].ContentType+'\r\n';
body = body + 'Content-transfer-encoding: base64\r\n\r\n';
body = body + attachments[0].Body+ '\r\n';
body = body + '-----------------------------153501500631101--\r\n';

req.setBody(body);
```

Comment: don't set the content-Length header. also you are base64 encoding the blob, but not indicating that as a content-encoding.

Comment: @superfell Attachment.Body is stored as [base64 encoded string](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm)... the use of [EncodingUtil](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm) was meant to convert it to a string  before sending. I will attempt to change the content length and 'compression' to match the base64 encoding **without** converting it to a string

Comment: @superfell, ok I followed your directions, still status 200, but nothing on the other end...

Comment: Create a RequestBin (http://requestb.in/) and post the data there - you should be able to see what's actually going over the wire.

Comment: @metadaddy http://requestb.in/1amhdg21?inspect so here is a request of the CURL with the same file- and the one coming out of salesforce using the _attachments[0].Body_ doesn't seem to have the file (256 bytes), so I've tried using **EncodingUtil.base64encode(Attachment[0].Body)** which gets the request size correct...

Comment: I would try the following: (1) Try it from the command line with curl, (2) Substitute a base64 encoding in your code as an explicit string - 'SGVsbG8gd29ybGQh' is 'Hello world!', and, if that works, (3) dump the body you're creating to debug and see what the difference is. Something weird is going on...

Comment: I ended up going another direction with the attachments (I just implemented an email handler) so no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this solution. It's a messing solution with Blob+HttpResponse I've proposed. http://enreeco.blogspot.it/2013/01/salesforce-apex-post-mutipartform-data.html

Comment: you've got it looks like an interesting workaround! Apex certainly makes some of this stuff difficult!

Comment: you don't know how much I messed up :)

Comment: yeah hence the reason I gave up and used an email attachment (at least my target environment had an email handler or I would have been SOL)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use EncodingUtil.urlEncode to ensure the form params. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm